# Apk build fail in jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1340746194): \\? 
\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0- 
 beta01.aar\01ea746f5d966b5b6980a3ad201cbcd2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
 AAPT err(Facade for 1340746194): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-beta01.aar\01ea746f5d966b5b6980a3ad201cbcd2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
```

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details
>   :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

**FAILURE**: Build failed with an exception.

- **What went wrong**:

  > Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
  >   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

Tried everything

> android.enableAapt2=false
>    android.enableBuildCache=false in gradle properties.  aaptOptions {         cruncherEnabled = false     }

still failing

Comment: If it gives aapt error, the problem is probably under resource folder. It gives a clue about a png file, could it be the problem?

Comment: `drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png` check this image or replace then run it again

Comment: @faruk and hemat it is working fine on local actually build fails on jenkins server only

Comment: @PiyushKumar that's right, you will not have a problem on local builds. I had a similar issue too. I had an html page in my res folder, and could build and run it successfully. However, release build did not allow this. I had to remove the html file. I believe this is a similar issue only happening on release build.

Answer (score 0):

if it gives aapt error it means error in resources not in your code
make sure you using PNG file .

also convert your png file from here and [Check this link](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png) put it in your project and try again hope your prob will solve

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by separating into smaller group of task

1. build assembleDebug
2. test
3. connectedAndroidTest

i had similar issues, when i ran assembleDebug and test together in Jenkins as a single task